# Preparing computers for remote MSI installation in NT4 domain

Tags: deployment, msi

We recently purchased EMCO Remote Installer to deploy MSI packages we're creating. We are still (unfortunately) in an NT4 domain, and when I try to deploy a package using domain's administrator credentials I'm getting "access denied". Under the "requirements for remote computers" section on the EMCO website (http://www.emco.is/products/remote-installer/requirements.php), it says that it requires remote machines to have:

```
* Started services: Computer Browser, Remote Registry
* File and Printer sharing enabled
* Windows Installer 3.1
* TCP ports opened: 135, 139, 445
* UDP ports opened: 137, 138
```

Is there any way of scripting these changes? If so, could someone get me started? I have about 200 machines I need to get this working with.

Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I'm going to say that you're up a creek. I didn't think that MSI technology can run on NT 4.0, and looking at the system requirements for [Windows Installer 3.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=889482FC-5F56-4A38-B838-DE776FD4138C&displaylang=en), it looks like it can't be installed on anything older than Win2k.

Actually, you're up a creek to begin with. The [system requirements](http://www.emco.is/products/remote-installer/requirements.php) (that you link to in your post) start at Win2k anyway. This product won't work against NT 4 systems. Sorry man. You could try packaging using a different product that actually supports NT 4.